# NODE JS: How can I make the following call wait for the called function to finish before proceeding

Tags: node.js, async-await

I still cannot wrap my mind around async/await functionality and I have tried several solutions unsuccessfully for the following scenario:

I have this function:

```
function addDataToDb(articleData) {

    initMongoDb();

    kanpionDb.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    kanpionDb.once('open', function () {
        SiteUrlModel.init().then(() => {
            articleData.forEach(articleItem => {
                var article = new SiteUrlModel(articleItem).save(function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("Failed: " + articleItem.siteName);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success " + articleItem.siteName);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

which is called from within following another file:

```
c.on('drain', async function () {
    Database.addDataToDb(ArticleList);
    console.log("All done");
});
```

**QUESTION: How can I make `console.log("All done")` only display the message after `Database.addDataToDb(ArticleList)` has finished executing?**

Comment: by putting it at the end of the async chain? E.g. after that whole `articleData.forEach()` block? However, what you probably want to do is either make this return a promise that resolves there, or pass in a callback and then run that once you reach that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is kind of messy because you have a big mixture of asynchronous techniques all mixed in the same function: events, promises and callbacks and then on top of that, there's a loop.  That is, indeed, a mess and is generally something you want to avoid.

The best overall solution to this level of complication is to back up a few steps and promisify all the basic asynchronous operations a few steps higher than this.  For your database, you should go find and use the promise interface to the database.  For your events, since these are both one-shot events you could build a promise wrapper on the object to get notified for the open and error events.

But, since I don't know all the components you're using I can't really do that part of it for you.  So, we'll look at what we could do to patch in appropriate promise-level support into this mixture of techniques.

```
const {promisify} = require('util');

function addDataToDb(articleData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        initMongoDb();

        kanpionDb.on('error', err => {
            console.error('connection error:', error);
            reject(error);
        });
        kanpionDb.once('open', function () {
            SiteUrlModel.init().then(() => {
                return Promise.all(articleData.map(articleItem => {
                    let model = new SiteUrlModel(articleItem);
                    model.savePromise = promisify(model.save);
                    return model.savePromise().then(() => {
                        console.log("Success " + articleItem.siteName);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log("Failed: " + articleItem.siteName);
                        throw err;
                    });
                }));
            }).then(resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}

// usage:
addDataToDb(articleData).then(() => {
    console.log("All Done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Summary of techniques:

1. Because of the events, we will have to wrap in a manually created promise that we resolve or reject when done.
2. The `.forEach()` loop gets replaced with `Promise.all(articleData.map(...))` which will give us a promise that tells us when all the saves are done.
3. The `.save(callback)` has to be replaced with a promisified version of `.save()`.  Ideally, you'd just use a promisified version of your  database interface here, but I've shown how to manually promisify the `.save()` function if necessary.
4. Hook up reject to the `error`event.
5. Hook up resolve and reject to the `SiteUrlModel.init()` promise.
6. Chain the `Promise.all()` promise to the `SiteUrlModel.init()` promise.

Comment: I was just trying it now because I was off all morning. Thanks a lot for the detailed and thorough explanation of everything. It worked brilliantly. I now have to put what you did in a blackboard and dissect. I think that will place me in a great path to understanding this.

Comment: I did not have to fix anything. It just plugged right in.

Answer (score 0):

if you could please try this,

```
const saveData = (articleItem) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var article = new SiteUrlModel(articleItem).save(function (error) {
        if (error) {
           console.log("Failed: " + articleItem.siteName);
           reject(error);
        } else {
           console.log("Success " + articleItem.siteName);
           resolve('Success');
        }
     });
  });
});

const addDataToDb = (articleData) => {
  const list = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    initMongoDb();

    kanpionDb.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    kanpionDb.once('open', function () {
      SiteUrlModel.init().then(() => {
        articleData.forEach(articleItem => {
          list.push(saveData(articleItem);
        });
      });
    });

    Promise.all(list).then(response => {
      resolve(response);
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    })
  });
};

c.on('drain', async function () {
  const result = Database.addDataToDb(ArticleList).then(res => {
    console.log("All done");
  });
});
```

I am trying to use the vanilla Promises

Comment: You have a `resolve()` and `reject()` inside a `.forEach()`.  That will not work properly.  It will resolve the promise on the first iteration of the `.forEach()` loop and will not wait for the loop to complete.

Comment: @Jfriend00 Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I was just giving the idea on how make use of promises which I had in mind.

Comment: Your new code is moving in the right direction, but it's going to call `Promise.all(list)` before `list` has anything in it.

Comment: I think Promise.all will work only if the list has a length

Comment: The `list` array will be empty when you call `Promise.all(list)` so it will not be able to wait for the `.forEach()` loop to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises to make the caller wait for your async code to finish. Refactor your `addDataToDb` function to return a promise and resolve/reject the promise accordingly. Since you've defined the "drain" callback to be an async function, you can use the `await` keyword inside your callback to make things a bit more concise:

```
c.on('drain', async function () {
    await Database.addDataToDb(ArticleList);
    console.log("All done");
});
```

Comment: That is one of a few solutions I tried, but did not work. @jfriend00 answer worked great.